# How much power do I need to charge 12 V 800 mAh NiMH battery

Tags: battery-charging, charger, nimh

I have a [cordless drill](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01G4MCVOK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with a 12 V 800 mAh NiMH battery. Somehow I lost its charger. I tried to charge the battery with another 12 V 1 A power supply, but it did not charge. So, how much voltage and current is needed to charge a 12 V 800 mAh NiMH battery?

Comment: Welcome! That's 800 mAh battery capacity. 800 mA is a current.

Comment: You don't know if the mains adapter is a power supply or a charger. Don't connect it anywhere unless you figure out if what you need is just a 12V supply or some exotic charger.

Comment: No such thing as an HiMH battery, presume this should say NiMH?

Comment: @Finbarr Chemistry is in the link.

Comment: Opps yeah, it s NiMH battery. Some weird autocorrection happened I think. Sorry for not cross-verifying the text before posting :|

Comment: "No such thing as an HiMH". That was my typo. Sorry. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: This sounds like a 10s configuration with a charge end voltage of 14.4 V. A 12 V supply cannot win there, you need a matching current limited charger or equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

> I lost its charger. I tried to charge the battery with another 12 1A power supply.

DO NOT attempt to charge a NiMH battery with a power supply. A NiMH charger is current limited, has a precise top voltage, and stops charging when it detects the fulls state of charge of the battery. A power supply isn't. Connecting a power supply to a NiMH battery will at best do nothing (if its voltage is too low) and at worst damage the power supply, the battery cells, or both.

Be safe: get a charger, the correct charger.

Comment: The photographs in the linked article make pretty clear that this is not a dedicated charger but a power brick.  Unfortunately, while it is readily apparent that this is pretty much a standard brick, the photographs are incomplete/fuzzy to a degree where I can neither decipher the rated voltage and amperage, nor can I reliably see the polarity of the connector.  Maybe some other photographs of the same product would be more determinative.

Comment: @user107063 It also can't be determined what kind of power brick it is. It may be a unregulated voltage supply, regulated voltage supply, or a special charger. So it might not be a standard brick.